# How to use css in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

css:

```
.level0 ul {list-style-type: none; height: 80px; width: 600px; margin: auto;}
    .level0 li {float: left;}
    .level1 ul {list-style-type: none; height: 80px; width: 600px; margin: auto;}
    .level1 li {float: left;}
    .level2 ul {list-style-type: none; height: 80px; width: 600px; margin: auto;}
    .level2 li {float: left;}
```

css in javascript:

```
    <script>
function getId(id){
           $('.level'+id +' ul').css('list-style-type: none', 'height: 80px', 'width: 600px', 'margin: auto');
            $('.level'+id +' li').css('float: left');
}
    </script>
```

When I use css normal is ok, but when using css in javascript is error, can you help me ?

Comment: You really _really_ need to read the documentation http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Er just do it the normal way?

Comment: Yes, I have a doc in api.jquery.com, but when use this code css jquery is not run

Answer (score 6):

Why didn't you [**read the `.css()` docs**](http://api.jquery.com/css/)?!

```
$('selector').css({
    attr: 'value',
    anotherattr: 'anothervalue'
});
```

Note that attrs use the JavaScript syntax for CSS attributes, i.e. *lowerCamelCase* instead of *lower-with-dashes*. That means `listStyleType` instead of `list-style-type` for example.

Besides that, only use `.css()` if you cannot use regular CSS. In many cases it's more appropriate to create a CSS class and the `.addClass()` this class.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass parameters to css method in two ways:

```
$('.level'+id +' ul').css("property","value");
```

or multiple properties using an javascript object:

```
$('.level'+id +' ul').css({"property1":"value1","property2","value2"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Bad syntax. You need squiggly brackets on multiple css items. Also, quote each element, not the whole entry. See below:

```
<script>
function getId(id){
       $('.level'+id +' ul').css({
           'listStyleType': 'none', 
           'height': '80px', 
           'width': '600px', 
           'margin': 'auto'
       });
        $('.level'+id +' li').css('float: left');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the Jquery code should be within $(document).ready(function()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.level'+id +' ul').css('list-style-type: none', 'height: 80px', 'width: 600px', 'margin: auto');
  $('.level'+id +' li').css('float: left');
});
```

otherwise the javascript is going to be called before the HTML exists and no css will be applied since there is not HTML to apply it to.

Comment: oh, and the squiggly brackets mentioned above ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need the syntax `$(selector).css('property', 'value');`  Check out the documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/css/

And a working sample I put up:

http://jsfiddle.net/awGrk/17/